# A\B Testing with Sorting

Tags: sampling, ab-test

In my company while splitting site users for AB test we do the following:

we choose parameters that seem the most important for us (for example: gender, life time value, average check, etc), if they are continuous we bin them, sort all our users based on this parameters in descending order, enumerate them and assign every 1st and 4th to A-group and every 2d and 3d to B-group. Is this a valid approach?

I feel that something is not right. Does this method have enough "randomness" in assigment to groups? If yes, then what is the difference between this approach and stratified sampling?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right that this is not totally randomized and one can construct scenarios where this will cause trouble. E.g. if your life time values look like this: 100, 10, 10, 10,  10, 1, 1, 1,  1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, etc., then clearly the A group will have much higher life time values than the B group. In other situations (e.g. 100, 99, 98, 97, 96 ...), the used approach will balance things out - at least as far as the mean of the shown values is concerned, which may of course not be what matters.

One might feel that this kind of thing happening is unlikely, but who knows.

Additionally, one might feel that to some extent the used method can actually result in better balance, because you make sure that half of the 4 highest values end up in group A and half in group B, which with totally random assignment is not necessarily the case. However, that you can overcome easily be stratified randomization. I.e. you still group your records in whatever way makes sense, then you randomly assign 2 to group A and 2 to group B within each block of 4 records. This is called "stratified" randomization, "blocked randomization", or "randomized block design" and is very commonly used in randomized clinical trials. A randomized block design gives you all the benefits of randomization and of balancing assignment within blocks.